# Showing git branch when listing directories - Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

just a quick question, is there any way to list the branches of different folders when listing those folders?

What i mean is, say you have a couple of folders with different projects and you want to do `ls -l` and also see which branch is in the different folders, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -l  | awk '{cmd="git --git-dir="$NF"/.git branch 2>/dev/null| grep ^*";system(cmd "> .tmp");getline branch < ".tmp";close(".tmp");print $0" "branch} END {cmd="rm -rf .tmp";system(cmd)}'
```

I'm not good at `awk` and this is just a rough solution.

Comment: Thanks that works pretty good, just need to do some trimming!

Answer (score 0):

This will print the directory and the current:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD \;
```

The output will be something like:

```
./dir<branch>
```

To improve the output with a space `./dir<space><branch>` this could work:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 -exec sh -c 'b=$(git --git-dir={}/.git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); echo " $b"' \;
```

To see all the branches this will work:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git branch \;
```

Notice the `rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` vs `branch`

It assumes you have multiple repositories within a directory, also you could also do a `pull` by replacing `branch` to keep all projects in sync.

An alias could become handy, something like:

```
alias pb='find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD \;'
```

Comment: Hi, i'm not able to use the command as you showed, i get an error from find like this: "find: paths must precede expression: 1". Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: `find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD \; ` ? that one, it can be indeed shorter: `find . -type d -depth 1 -print0 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git branch \;` I tried  on a macOS within the directory containing the projects